# Redirect URL with no filename

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need to redirct the following url:

https://www.domain.de/?topic=bla&ID=11111&serie=2222

to

https://www.domain.de

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^?topic=(.*)$ https://www.domain.de [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} topic [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.domain.de? [R=301,L]
```